# How to add all in one seo pack tags to the post from a php?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, insert

I am using a php file like "sitename.com/folder/file.php" to post everyday automatically in wordpress. The code is something like that;

```
$my_post = array(); 
$my_post['post_title'] = '<title>';
$my_post['post_content'] = '<content>';
$my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
$my_post['post_author'] = 1;
$my_post['post_category'] = array(16); 
$post_ids = wp_insert_post($my_post);
```

I want to add SEO Title, SEO Description and SEO Keywords for this post and I am using AIOSP plugin for SEO. What code should be added to have this areas filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin most likely stores the SEO fields as post meta.

I use the Yoast plugin which creates a bunch of key-value pairs for the post in the wp_postmeta table. Your AIOSP probably works the same way.

Your best bet is to manually create a post with all the SEO info then look in the wp_postmeta table and pick out the fields.

Then use the add_post_meta() function in your automated script to programatically add the SEO data.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta